# How do I efficiently update dataframe values by variable group based on multiple criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

input_df:

```
name  name_group  value
foo1          a       2
foo2          a       2
foo3          a       2
foo4          a       2
bar1          b
bar2          b
bar3          b
buzz1         c       6
buzz2         c       6
buzz3         c       6
buzz4         c       6
buzz5         c       6
```

Where every row in each name_group has the same "value", so in this case every name in name_group "a" has the same "value", every name in name_group "b" has the same "value", etc.

I want to create a new column "new_vals" that is equal to the min(# of rows in that "name_group", "value" column). If there are missing values in the "value" column for any "name_group", it should just use the # of rows in that "name_group". For my example dataframe, the desired output is:

output_df:

```
name  name_group  value   new_vals
foo1          a       2          2
foo2          a       2          2
foo3          a       2          2
foo4          a       2          2
bar1          b                  3
bar2          b                  3
bar3          b                  3
buzz1         c       6          5
buzz2         c       6          5
buzz3         c       6          5
buzz4         c       6          5
buzz5         c       6          5
```

Currently, the way I am achieving this is by looping through each unique value in the "name_group" column, finding the # of rows in that name_group, comparing it to the value in the "value" column, then setting the value of the "new_val" column based on the min value between the two. The results of this for each "name_group" are concatenated to another dataframe until i have my final output.

While this method works, I feel as though there must be a more efficient way to do this rather than taking subsets the starting dataframe, processing each "name_group" separately, then combining everything back together. Does anyone have a more pythonic/efficient way of reproducing this functionality?

Here's some code reflecting my current process:

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
for name_group in input_df['name_group'].unique():
    # process the data one name group at a time
    temp_df = input_df.loc[input_df['name_group'] == name_group]

    max_val = temp_df['value'].max()
    name_group_cnt = temp_df.shape[0]

    # if the "value" column is empty, set new_val equal to the number of
    # rows in that name_group
    if max_val == '':
        new_val = name_group_cnt
    else:
        new_val = min(max_val, name_group_cnt)

    temp_df['new_val'] = new_val
    output_df = pd.concat([output_df, temp_df])
```

Answer (score 2):

I will using `transform` and `np.where`

```
s=df.groupby('name_group').name_group.transform('count')
df['New']=np.where(s>df.value,df.value,s)
df
Out[13]: 
     name name_group  value  New
0    foo1          a    2.0  2.0
1    foo2          a    2.0  2.0
2    foo3          a    2.0  2.0
3    foo4          a    2.0  2.0
4    bar1          b    NaN  3.0
5    bar2          b    NaN  3.0
6    bar3          b    NaN  3.0
7   buzz1          c    6.0  5.0
8   buzz2          c    6.0  5.0
9   buzz3          c    6.0  5.0
10  buzz4          c    6.0  5.0
11  buzz5          c    6.0  5.0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the NaN values. I'm getting a type error when comparing the values of s to the value column. 

My error message is:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a temporary `count` and then compare values.

```
vs = df.groupby("new_group").size().to_dict()
# vs =  {'a': 4, 'c': 5, 'b': 3}

df["count"] = df["new_group"].apply(lambda k: vs[k])

def comp(row):
    if row["value"] is np.nan: return row["count"]
    return min(row["value"], row["count"])

df["new_vals"] = df.apply(comp, 1)
# equivalent to 
# df = df[['value', 'count']].min(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
new_group  value  count  new_vals
   0   a    2.0      4       2.0
   1   a    2.0      4       2.0
   2   a    2.0      4       2.0
   3   a    2.0      4       2.0
   4   b    NaN      3       3,0
   5   b    NaN      3       3.0
   6   b    NaN      3       3.0
   7   c    6.0      5       5.0
   8   c    6.0      5       5.0       
   9   c    6.0      5       5.0
   10  c    6.0      5       5.0
   11  c    6.0      5       5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. The idea is to calculate the number of rows per `name_group` and merge that into your dataframe as a new column (called `count`). Then `new_vals` will just be calculated as the minimum of the `value` and `count` columns:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('name_group').size().reset_index(name='count'), on='name_group')

df['new_vals'] = df[['value', 'count']].min(axis=1)
```

Then you can drop the `count` column if you want, using `df.drop(columns='count', inplace=True)`, to give:

```
     name name_group  value  new_vals
0    foo1          a    2.0       2.0
1    foo2          a    2.0       2.0
2    foo3          a    2.0       2.0
3    foo4          a    2.0       2.0
4    bar1          b    NaN       3.0
5    bar2          b    NaN       3.0
6    bar3          b    NaN       3.0
7   buzz1          c    6.0       5.0
8   buzz2          c    6.0       5.0
9   buzz3          c    6.0       5.0
10  buzz4          c    6.0       5.0
11  buzz5          c    6.0       5.0
```